# Creating WCF Service that returns a MySqlCommand object in it's only method

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I created a WCF Service on visual studio 2015 with one method that returns a MySqlCommand. When i try to add a reference of the service on another service i get an error:

> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:54740/GetCommand.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:54740/GetCommand.svc'.
>   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by the service.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>   The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I have searched a lot and i cannot find a solution, the code for the service is as follows:

```
 public class GetCommand : IGetCommand
{
    public MySqlCommand getCmd(string q, MySqlConnection con)
    {
        return new MySqlCommand(q, con);
    }
}
```

and the contract code is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGetSqlConnection
{
    [OperationContract]
    MySqlConnection getConnection(string query);
}
```

The service is found when i press the discover button, but i cannot add it as a reference. All the other services of the solution are working.

Comment: are you adding it as a `Reference or a Service Reference -> Web Service` ?

Comment: I'm adding a Service Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySqlCommand` is an unknown type for the client, you should reference the assembly that contains its definition.
Anyway what you are doing has not much sense. Once your client obtains an instance of a `MySqlCommand` how can it use it? The client is usually on another machine plus the command has a connection with it (and maybe a transaction).
In addition I don't think that the type `MySqlCommand` is serializable.

Comment: I am testing things that can be done mostly, this is not an application that was gonna be used in the real world. I think the serializability of the type is the answer to my question! Thanks a lot !